# JBuilder as_json to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

Does Jbuilder use as_json or to_json to render?

I am attempting to override the as_json and to_json with an alias, similar to the below:

```
  module BSON
    class ObjectId

      def as_json(*args)
        to_s
      end

      alias :to_json :as_json

    end
  end
```

Then use JBuilder to render the return object. However, it acts as if it is using neither to_json or as_json to render.

Answer (score 0):

Jbuilder uses MultiJson, which by default will use the JSON gem. That gem is currently tangled with ActiveSupport's all-Ruby #to_json implementation.

Reference: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jbuilder/2.5.0